# Is there a way to convert a yaml to a dataframe? Or somehow flatten or normalize many data sets rendered as JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dataframe

I have multiple data sets that look something like this:

```
{'class': 'pipesteps.validate.Validate', 'conf': {'schema_def': {'fields': [{'data_type': 'STRING', 'name': 'Operation'}, {'data_type': 'STRING', 'name': 'SNL_Institution_Key'}, {'data_type': 'INTEGER', 'name': 'SNL_Funding_Key'}, {'data_type': 'STRING', 'name': 'CUSIP'}, {'data_type': 'STRING', 'name': 'SEDOL_NULL'}, {'data_type': 'STRING', 'name': 'Ticker'}, {'data_type': 'DATETIME', 'name': 'Date_of_Closing_Price'}, {'data_type': 'FLOAT', 'name': 'Total_Return_MTD'}, {'data_type': 'FLOAT', 'name': 'TR_SNL_Peer_Index_Change'}, {'data_type': 'FLOAT', 'name': 'TR_SNL_Broad_Index_Change'}, {'data_type': 'FLOAT', 'name': 'TR_SandP_500'}, {'data_type': 'DATETIME', 'name': 'Beginning_Pricing_Date'}]}}, 'id': 'validate'}
```

Pretty much everything is organized as 'datatype' or 'name'.

There are dozens and dozens of these data sets embedded in a text file.  Each set begins with `'class': 'pipesteps.validate.Validate'` and ends with `'id': 'validate'`.  I am trying to organize this data into a single data frame, or somehow flatten/normalize it, so it is easier for a person to read.  How can I do that?

I'm guessing there is a simple and straightforward method to do all of this, but after searching on Google for a while, I still can't find a solution, so I'm back here.  TIA.

Comment: Where is the YAML?

Comment: @d_kennetz I asked "where". I am familiar with YAML, there is none in the question. It's a parsed structure of dictionaries and lists, the question seemingly has nothing to do with YAML

Comment: @roganjosh hence why I deleted my return comment :P. Misread what you said.

Comment: @d_kennetz on my phone so I get a delayed view :) OP: YAML has several formatting options that actually make it, IMO, possibly more readable than JSON. Coupled with you having already parsed it out of YAML format into something easily dumpable as JSON, I don't know what you're looking for.

Comment: Would you only want the middle 'conf' section in your result df or all of it?

Comment: essentially you seem to want to recurse the middle section until you arrive at a df?

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379981/a-user-decided-he-did-not-want-his-data-on-the-web-so-he-removed-it-from-my-ans).

Answer (score 3):

This will recursively extract out values into a flattened dict and each level of 'flattening' will combined into a final string for each key. So if level of flattening was 0 (object already was a dict) it will be as you'd expect like class: pipesteps.validate.Validate. If it is deep then you will see what will happen:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

a = {'class': 'pipesteps.validate.Validate', 'conf': {'schema_def': {'fields': [{'data_type': 'STRING', 'name': 'Operation'}, {'data_type': 'STRING', 'name': 'SNL_Institution_Key'}, {'data_type': 'INTEGER', 'name': 'SNL_Funding_Key'}, {'data_type': 'STRING', 'name': 'CUSIP'}, {'data_type': 'STRING', 'name': 'SEDOL_NULL'}, {'data_type': 'STRING', 'name': 'Ticker'}, {'data_type': 'DATETIME', 'name': 'Date_of_Closing_Price'}, {'data_type': 'FLOAT', 'name': 'Total_Return_MTD'}, {'data_type': 'FLOAT', 'name': 'TR_SNL_Peer_Index_Change'}, {'data_type': 'FLOAT', 'name': 'TR_SNL_Broad_Index_Change'}, {'data_type': 'FLOAT', 'name': 'TR_SandP_500'}, {'data_type': 'DATETIME', 'name': 'Beginning_Pricing_Date'}]}}, 'id': 'validate'}

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    # some recursion
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out

flat_json = flatten_json(a)
df = (json_normalize(flat_json)).T # .T because it makes a DF of 1 row and 26 columns and I didn't like that
```

If you don't want it transposed and just want 26 columns because it will probably be easier to access data that way then just take off the .T at the end of the df

output:

```
>>> df
                                                           0
class                                pipesteps.validate.Validate
conf_schema_def_fields_0_data_type                        STRING
conf_schema_def_fields_0_name                          Operation
conf_schema_def_fields_10_data_type                        FLOAT
conf_schema_def_fields_10_name                      TR_SandP_500
conf_schema_def_fields_11_data_type                     DATETIME
conf_schema_def_fields_11_name            Beginning_Pricing_Date
conf_schema_def_fields_1_data_type                        STRING
conf_schema_def_fields_1_name                SNL_Institution_Key
conf_schema_def_fields_2_data_type                       INTEGER
conf_schema_def_fields_2_name                    SNL_Funding_Key
conf_schema_def_fields_3_data_type                        STRING
conf_schema_def_fields_3_name                              CUSIP
conf_schema_def_fields_4_data_type                        STRING
conf_schema_def_fields_4_name                         SEDOL_NULL
conf_schema_def_fields_5_data_type                        STRING
conf_schema_def_fields_5_name                             Ticker
conf_schema_def_fields_6_data_type                      DATETIME
conf_schema_def_fields_6_name              Date_of_Closing_Price
conf_schema_def_fields_7_data_type                         FLOAT
conf_schema_def_fields_7_name                   Total_Return_MTD
conf_schema_def_fields_8_data_type                         FLOAT
conf_schema_def_fields_8_name           TR_SNL_Peer_Index_Change
conf_schema_def_fields_9_data_type                         FLOAT
conf_schema_def_fields_9_name          TR_SNL_Broad_Index_Change
id                                                      validate
```

Comment: Thanks for the trying to help.  Your code seems to eliminate a whole bunch of  data sets.  In my original data set, I had 'c3_Month_T_Bill' 28x.  In the parsed version, I have 'c3_Month_T_Bill' 4x.  It seems like your script is taking unique named and data types, and flattening those, but all the others get kicked out....somehow.  I want to keep all the data sets, even though they repeat multiple times.  These data sets are tables, field names, and data types.  The field names and data types can show up multiple times, but each combination of these is in a different table.  Thanks.

Comment: so in your example data you have multiple dictionaries, named exactly the same. I did not set an iterator up for dict types because it didn't seem like I needed to, but yes if it finds a dict that has the exact same name as a previous dict it wont work in its current state, but it also a super easy fix.... you just add an iterator to every conditional.

Comment: Yeah, I think this should be kind of easy, but I got going in the wrong direction with this, apparently, and now I'm kind of getting off track here.  Is there a simple solution for this.  It seems like there should be a library that handles this kind of thing, but I couldn't find anything useful.  Google is great, but it doesn't solve all problems.

Comment: I think the only solution for nested jsons with varying data types is recursion. I do not know of any simple libraries for it, but that doesn't mean there aren't any. Indeed, Dr. Google knows a lot, but not all!